# How to execute a script when a page finishes loading, using a custom Firefox addon?

Tags: firefox, javascript

Objective: To run a script which will automatically "click" the radio button on Google's search page, to activate the Dark theme.

I have a [script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/171299/how-to-invoke-the-dark-theme-selection-on-googles-search-page) which on its own, is capable of changing the google page theme to dark.
`document.querySelector('div[role="dialog"] g-radio-button-group:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-child(2)').click();`.

Since I couldn't get it to run via GreaseMonkey and TamperMonkey, I tried creating my own addon, but even though a red border is shown (via `borderify.js`), my script isn't getting executed. How do I get the script to run once the page loads? As far as I can see, the script should have run on page load. Did I do something wrong?

**mainfest.json:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Google Script Runner",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Runs a script on www.google.com after page load",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "webNavigation"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["script.js", "borderify.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**background.js:**

```
// Called when a navigation is completed
function handleNavigationCompleted(details) {
  alert('entered')
  if (details.url.includes('www.google.com')) {
    // Inject the content script when the page has loaded
    browser.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, { file: 'script.js' });
  }
}
alert('executed')
// Listen for navigation completed events
browser.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(handleNavigationCompleted);
```

**borderify.js:**

```
document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";
```

**script.js:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  if (window.location.href.includes('www.google.com')) {
    document.querySelector('div[role="dialog"] g-radio-button-group:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-child(2)').click();
  }
});
```

**What else I tried:**

- Used `document.addEventListener("load", function(){` in `scripts.js`,
  but no point if `background.js` isn't getting invoked.
- Inserted   `if (window.location.href.includes('www.google.com')) {document.querySelector('div[role="dialog"] g-radio-button-group:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-child(2)').click();}`
  into `borderify.js`, but it makes the theme dark only when I reload
  the addon. After that, if I manually make the theme "Light" and then
  refresh the page, the addon does not make the theme "Dark".

[image]

[image]

[image]